# Start vim without vimrc / change vimrc with open files

Tags: vim

I have 2 .vimrc configuration files `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vimsqlrc`.

Is there a way I can source either of them (switch from one to another) while I have some files already opened?
As an extension, how do I turn off the loading of vimrc (i.e, don't use any vimrc) while I have files open?

Comment: Isn't `:source filename` working?

Comment: The vimrc is sourced once when vim is loaded. It is never sourced again (unless you manually source it). (So I think the answer to your question is you can't)

Comment: @Adrian No it itsn't.

Comment: @FDinoff Do you have some links as references?

Comment: @ansh0l probably `:h initilization` or `:h vimrc`. What are the differences between the two vimrc? It seems like you might be able to go with per filetype settings.

Comment: @FDinoff Nothing much - some imap variations and tab and indentation  settings.

Comment: @ansh0l, take a moment to read the link in my answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your `~/.vimrc` is read and executed only once. If you want to nullify it with another file, you'll have to change the value of every single option and unmap every single mapping in, of course, both files. This sounds like a *very* bad and unnecessarily complex idea.

If you want another environment, just use another environment:

```
$ vim                 <-- starts Vim normally, reading ~/.vimrc
$ vim -u ~/.vimsqlrc  <-- starts Vim using your alternative vimrc
$ vim -u NONE         <-- starts Vim without any vimrc
$ vim -u NORC         <-- starts Vim without any vimrc, but with plugins
```

but I'm afraid you'll have to stop and restart Vim for that.

Anyway, your question has a very strong [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) smell. Do you want to have specific settings for `*.sql` files?

If that's your goal, you can put your settings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim` like this:

```
setlocal autoindent
nnoremap <buffer> <F6> :echo "F6"<CR>
```

Using `setlocal` for options and `<buffer>` for mappings ensures that your settings are only applied for `*.sql` files.

Comment: With his last comment this is exactly what he wants

Comment: @FDinoff, yeah, that's what I thought while watching the comments count grow.

Comment: @romainl Not exactly *.sql files. Say I have a file which has sql statements littered every here and there.
Now, whenever I want to edit such a file, the default vimrc settings are applied, even if all I want to do is fiddle around with the sql once I have the file open.

Comment: Another option is to simply put specific sql settings in your vimrc like this: `autocmd Filetype sql (do something)`.  Especially if you only have a few settings for sql files which you want to change, I like this option better than creating a new file.